# Facing error in using 'connect-mongo' in the given code. Cannot read 'create' property of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to save the session of my login page so that whenever server starts the user is logged in.
So basically this is my code in which i am getting error :

```
    const express = require('express');
    const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
    const app = express();
    const port = 8000;
    const expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts');
    const db = require('./config/mongoose');
    //used for session cookie
    const session = require('express-session');
    const passport = require('passport');
    const passportLocal = require('./config/passport-local-strategy');
    const MongoStore = require('connect-mongo').default;
    
    app.use(express.urlencoded());
    
    app.use(cookieParser());
    
    app.use(express.static('./assets'));    
    
    app.set('view engine' , 'ejs');
    app.set('views' , './views');
    
    
    app.use(session({
        store :  MongoStore.create(
            {
                mongoUrl : db,
                autoRemove : 'disabled'
            },
            function(err){
                console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
            }
        )
    }));
    
    app.use(passport.initialize());
    app.use(passport.session());
    
    
    app.use(passport.setAuthenticatedUser);
    
    app.use('/' , require('./routes'));
```

*The error occurs at :*

````
```store :  MongoStore.create(
        {
            mongoUrl : db,
            autoRemove : 'disabled'
        },
        function(err){
            console.log(err || 'connect-mongodb setup ok');
        }
    )```
````

Error is :-  store :  MongoStore.create(

TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure out why this error is occurring.

Comment: I don't think you need the `.default` in `require('connect-mongo').default`

Comment: @RobBailey I tried to do that too but different type of error came i.e.,  MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed at parseConnectionString, connect etc etc.

Comment: That parseConnectionString error means that your `db` URL is incorrect. `mongoUrl : db,`

Comment: I have checked my db URL but it seems correct to me because when I remove the 'connect-mongo' part, it works fine. Although the error is not only consist of  parseConnectionString but it also consist of many other fields like this :  MongoParseError: URI malformed, cannot be parsed
    at parseConnectionString (C:\Users\prath\Desktop\HTML\node\codeial\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\uri_parser.js:568:21)
    at connect (C:\Users\prath\Desktop\HTML\node\codeial\node_modules\connect-mongo\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\connect.js:282:3)
    at .... and many more

Comment: @RobBailey yeah I got that now. There is problem in db URL. Thanks for helping me out!